# Is this a secure way to connect to mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli

I plan to use the following connection script as an include on other php scripts. My question is if I use my browser and go to this file directly I get the following message...
"Connection failed: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

My question is should I get this message accessing the connection script directly or should I be connecting to the db. If I should be connecting, what is to prevent someone else from guessing the url of my connection script and what can they do if they do. Also if I should be connecting, why would I be getting this error as I have given the user all access privilages.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$db = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully. ";
?>
```

Comment: if you dont want the fil accessed directly move it outside the web root - but as your connection does not even work - you may want to worry about that first

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

Comment: Ok so i should be connecting

Comment: You should get a successful connection from visiting that script directly (so if you don't connect you probably have wrong info typed in, but that's another question), and if that's all there is (no other code), there's really nothing anyone can do with it if they guess the link. However, you can (and in my opinion should) place all configuration- and include-files outside the public folder.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. What if I put this script in a password protected folder or should move it out of the public_html folder?

Comment: if you put that in a password protected folder, you and/or visitors to your site will have to enter a password. May not be a good idea. Place it outside public and turn off reporting.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advise. I will now troubleshoot why I'm not connecting

Comment: With the given script, nobody can do anything. If there is more code, it depends on what that other code does